# Running ARCore project on the emulator(android studio) using webcam

Tags: android, android-emulator, arcore

I am trying out ARCore. After running the sample hello_ar_java project on the emulator using a virtual background, I decided to check how it would work with just the webcam input. Hoping it would detect the surfaces atleast.But It kept crashing and it showed the detected point cloud a couple of time but no surfaces were detected. Has anyone tried this and had better results? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made the correct settings for your app? And also for your emulator?
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/emulator

Comment: yes , it worked on the said emulator configuration in a virtual environment, though it wouldnt detect surfaces everytime. when I change the back camera to a webcam input, it just wouldnt detect any surfaces . @rosu alin

Comment: it may not detect any surface because of low lightning